# Using iText to open PDF documents after writing to them

Tags: java, pdf, itext, jfreechart, paragraphs

Im using iText and the Document class in a JFrame to write PDFs but if i try to use the Runtime class to run it after creation i get an exception that i cant open it due to the locks still on it and if i run Unlocker on it, my JFrame has a lock token on it. How do i open the PDF if i want to write to it?

```
Document d = new Document();
.... code
d.close();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:/PDFChartStuff.pdf");
```

Why does this post not meet stackoverflow's "quality standards"?

Comment: Who said it doesn't meet "quality standards"? How could you imagine that while posting?

Comment: I kept trying to hit post and it kept telling me "This post does not meet the quality standards". It finally let me post it after i put that sentence in

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/163188).

Comment: ok now i need the actual question :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using windows you can use `rundll32` to launch a pdf file.

Try something like this

```
String pdfFile="D:/PDFChartStuff.pdf";
if (pdfFile.toString().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + pdfFile);
            } else {
               //For cross platform use
                Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                desktop.open(pdfFile);
            }
```

Comment: desktop.open(pdfFile);  --> this line is not working. open() method is showing String as incompatible type.